# How to enumerate all possibilities for brute-force algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

This question may be not specified, but I think it is very important. When you want to solve a optimization problem and you are not very familiar with `dynamic programming` method, it is the first idea that comes to you mind.

I can give some simple examples:

- get min element of a list (very simple)
- list all permutation of a set
- list all subset of a set

These problem all have mature method. But there are problem not very clear:

- list all `edit distance` of two string (i mean not the shortest one of edit operation)
- list all `common subsequence` of two sequence
- list all possibilities of parenthesizing `matrix chain multiplication`

I have no idea about solving these problems with brute-force method. My question is:

Is there a systematic generic method for list all the possibilities with brute-force algorithm?

Comment: I think this question is too vague to answer.  There are a huge number of different combinatorial structures (things like subsets, combinations, permutations, trees, etc.) that you can search over, and there are entire books dedicated to how to enumerate them (see, for example, "The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4A.")

Comment: "The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4A." is helpful. Thank you, @templatetypedef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)* is one of the most general methods for finding all solutions to a problem.  Per wikipedia,

> Backtracking is a general algorithm for finding all (or some) solutions to some computational problem, that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions, and abandons each partial candidate c ("backtracks") as soon as it determines that c cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution.
>
> The classic textbook example of the use of backtracking is the eight queens puzzle, that asks for all arrangements of eight chess queens on a standard chessboard so that no queen attacks any other.

Two of the problems you mention,
• list all common subsequence of two sequence
• list all possibilities of parenthesizing matrix chain multiplication
can be easily handled using backtracking.  I am not sure about the edit-distance question.